# Taking File Inputs in OpenCL?

Tags: c, opencl, dot-product

I'm new to OpenCL, and I'm curious as to how to read in data input to perform simple operations (e.g. cross/dot product) on.

For a particular example, I've compiled and am trying to run this simple sample code to calculate a 3D dot product from vectors: https://github.com/mattscar/opencl_dot_product

However, I'm not sure how to format the input for the code. In the following code snippet:

```
/* Create program from file */
program = clCreateProgramWithSource(ctx, 1, 
  (const char**)&program_buffer, &program_size, &err);
 if(err < 0) {
  perror("Couldn't create the program");
  exit(1);
}
```

clCreateProgramWithSource appears to operate on context ctx, but I don't know how to assign the context to a file on my hard drive to read test vector data from. Am I going about this the right way?

Comment: To my understanding, the source should simply be the vector values (e.g. 13 17 45) should they not?

Comment: According to https://www.khronos.org/registry/cl/sdk/1.0/docs/man/xhtml/clCreateProgramWithSource.html It's basically an array of strings. The array are the program lines, and the strings are each line. length should be null, if the lines are null terminated. So in a nut shell, you'll probably going to want to read a file line by line, terminating each line with null and then load it into program buffer (remember, it's an array of pointers, so you'll need to allocate memory for each pointer most likely) the second argument is basically how many lines.

Comment: It would be good to see the code you used to load the program before passing it to this function btw.

Comment: I have a feeling this is an XY problem. Could you elaborate or clarify what you are actually trying to do?

Answer (score 2):

One approach to this is as follows:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#ifdef __APPLE__
#include <OpenCL/opencl.h>
#else
#include <CL/cl.h>
#endif

int main() {

    cl_platform_id platform;
    cl_device_id device;
    cl_context context;
    cl_program program;

    FILE* programHandle;
    size_t programSize, kernelSourceSize;
    char *programBuffer, *kernelSource;

    // get first available platform and gpu and create context
    clGetPlatformIDs(1, &platform, NULL);
    clGetDeviceIDs(platform, CL_DEVICE_TYPE_GPU, 1, &device, NULL);
    context = clCreateContext(NULL, 1, &device, NULL, NULL, NULL);

    // get size of kernel source
    programHandle = fopen("kernel.cl", "r");
    fseek(programHandle, 0, SEEK_END);
    programSize = ftell(programHandle);
    rewind(programHandle);

    // read kernel source into buffer
    programBuffer = (char*) malloc(programSize + 1);
    programBuffer[programSize] = '\0';
    fread(programBuffer, sizeof(char), programSize, programHandle);
    fclose(programHandle);

    // create program from buffer
    program = clCreateProgramWithSource(context, 1,
            (const char**) &programBuffer, &programSize, NULL);
    free(programBuffer);

    // read kernel source back in from program to check
    clGetProgramInfo(program, CL_PROGRAM_SOURCE, 0, NULL, &kernelSourceSize);
    kernelSource = (char*) malloc(kernelSourceSize);
    clGetProgramInfo(program, CL_PROGRAM_SOURCE, kernelSourceSize, kernelSource, NULL);
    printf("nKernel source:nn%sn", kernelSource);
    free(kernelSource);

    clReleaseContext(context);
    return 0;

}
```

Courtesy of http://dhruba.name/2012/08/16/opencl-cookbook-creating-programs-and-reading-kernels-from-a-file/

Specifically this part :

```
 // get size of kernel source
        programHandle = fopen("kernel.cl", "r");
        fseek(programHandle, 0, SEEK_END);
        programSize = ftell(programHandle);
        rewind(programHandle);

        // read kernel source into buffer
        programBuffer = (char*) malloc(programSize + 1);
        programBuffer[programSize] = '\0';
        fread(programBuffer, sizeof(char), programSize, programHandle);
        fclose(programHandle);

        // create program from buffer
        program = clCreateProgramWithSource(context, 1,
                (const char**) &programBuffer, &programSize, NULL);
        free(programBuffer);
```

You need to know the size of what you're reading, so seek to the end

```
fseek(programHandle, 0, SEEK_END);
```

Then get that position

```
programSize = ftell(programHandle);
```

which should be the size.

Then you rewind to reset file position.

```
rewind(programHandle);
```

It's important that you allocate enough memory to store entire program + null terminator that you have to add yourself.

Read the file into allocated space, then set it's last index to null.

```
programBuffer = (char*) malloc(programSize + 1);
programBuffer[programSize] = '\0';
```

Read in your code and then close your file.

```
fread(programBuffer, sizeof(char), programSize, programHandle);
fclose(programHandle);
```

Now you have 1 row of code, so thats count, you know the size of that 1 line, so thats length. And null to indicate it's null terminated. Done.

```
program = clCreateProgramWithSource(context, 1, (const char**) &programBuffer, &programSize, NULL);
free(programBuffer);
```

Don't forget to release your program buffer when youre done.